# heroku h10 error messgae on python flask app

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I keep trying to run a flask app through heroku but I keep getting the same H10 error message and have no clue why.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/')
def math():
    #return(y)
    return render_template('index.html', variable = output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

here is my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT flaskapp:app
```

here is my requirements.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
Click==7.0
cycler==0.10.0
distlib==0.3.0
dominate==2.4.0
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
joblib==0.14.1
kiwisolver==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.0
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==1.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
scikit-learn==0.22.2
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.14.0
sklearn==0.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.13
virtualenv==20.0.7
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==1.0.0
zipp==3.0.0
```

here is the error message:

```
2020-03-28T03:03:09.881692+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stock-price-guru.herokuapp.com request_id=c9352003-7178-422e-9cc3-bb00de12b444 fwd="99.245.86.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-28T03:03:10.458710+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stock-price-guru.herokuapp.com request_id=20a0814d-4929-46b9-9843-574df84125fd fwd="99.245.86.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: was it fixed? if so what was the solution

Comment: Never ended up fixing it, hosted on github pages